# If $ \frac{X_n}{1024^n} $ is an odd integer, find the smallest possible value of $n$, where $n\ge2$ is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> For each integer $k\ge2$, the decimal expansions of the numbers $1024, 1024^2, \dots, 1024^k$ are concatenated, in that order, to obtain a number $X_k$.  (For example, $X_2 = 10241048576$.)  If $ \frac{X_n}{1024^n}$ is an odd integer, find the smallest possible value of $n$, where $n\ge2$ is an integer..

- The answer is $\boxed{5}.$
- I tried for $X_1,X_2,X_3$ and noticed they weren't coming out as integers.

After this, the numbers were too big.

- I think that we can also try expanding  $X_i$ terms. But then we would like t know the number of digits in $X_i.$
  For example,
  we have
- $$X_2 = 1024 \cdot 10^7 + 1024^2 = 2^{17} \cdot 5^7 + 2^{20} = 2^{17} (5^7 + 2^3).$$
  So $$X_2/{1024^2}$$which is not a integer.
- $$X_3= 1024 \cdot 10^{17} + 1024^2 \cdot 10^{10} + 1024^3 = 2^{27} \cdot 5^{17} + 2^{30} \cdot 5^{10} + 2^{30} = 2^{27} (5^{17} + 2^3 \cdot 5^{10} + 2^3). $$
- We have $$V_2(X_3)<V_2(1024^3).$$

Any hints?

Comment: You're close. Think about what the general expression for $X_n$ should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $1024$ is just a little larger than $10^3, 1024^k$ will be a little larger than $10^{3k}$, so will have $3k+1$ decimal digits.  According to [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1024%5Ek%20%3E%2010%5E%7B3k%2B1%7D), the number of digits does not increase above this until $k=98$.  I think you can rely on $n$ being smaller than that.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this is posted as an answer, as opposed to a comment.

Comment: @CalvinLin:  It is the one clear question asked in the post

Comment: I am not going to lie this post actually helped me solved the problem, the reason is, it gave a nice hint, which is what I asked. This hint helped me answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Find a nice way to write $X_n$, so that it's easy to manipulate $X_n / 1024^n$.
In fact, it is exactly what you wrote at the start for $X_2, X_3$, you just need to generalize it. (You didn't get the manipulation part though.)

> $X_n = 1024^n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 1024^i \times 10^{a_i}$, where $a_i$ is to be determined.  Then,
>  $$ \frac{X_n}{1024^n} = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{2^{a_i} \times 5^{a_i} } { 2^{10 (n-i)}}.$$
>  Now, study this expression.

---

Here's a complete (to me) solution. Fill in the details as needed.
If you're stuck, show your work when asking for help.

- Let $b_i = \lfloor i \times 10 \times \log_{10} 2 \rfloor + 1$. Show that the first 5 terms are $b_i = 4, 7, 10, 13, 16$.
- Show that since $2^{10} > 10^3$, hence $b_i \geq 3i+1$. (As Ross points out, $b_i = 3i+1$ for $ i \leq 97$.)
- Fix $n$. Show that $a_{n-1} = b_{n-1}, a_{i-1} = a_i + b_i,$ so $a_i$ can be determined recursively.
- Show that if $ a_i > 10 (n-i)$, then the corresponding term in the summation expression of $X_n / 1024^n$ is an even integer.
- Show that if $ a_i = 10 (n-i)$, then the corresponding term in the summation expression of $X_n / 1024^n$ is an odd integer.
- Show that if $ a_i > 10 (n-i)$,  $\forall i < n$, then $X_n / 1024^n$ is an odd integer (because of the initial term 1).
- Show that for $n=5$, $a_4 = 16, a_3 = 29, a_2 = 39, a_1 = 46$.
- Show that for $ n \geq 6$, $a_i > 10 (n-i)$ for $ i < n$. (We're adding a lot of terms that are bigger than 10 at the start, so this should be "obvious".)
- Conclude that for $n \geq 5$, $X_n$ is an odd integer.
- Show that for $ n= 4$, $a_3 = 13, a_2 = 23, a_1 = 30$.
- Conclude that for $n=4$, $X_n$ is an even integer because $a_1  = 10 (4-1)$ and $a_i > 10 (n-i)$ otherwise.
- Conclude that for $n = 3, 2$, $X_n$ is not an integer.
  (It is easy to calculate directly as you did. If you want to use my method, show that it's equal to $\frac{ \text{odd}}{2^k}$, hence not an integer.)

---

Notes

- Yes, for clarity of expression, I should have used $a_{n, i }$ so that $a_n$ doesn't do double-duty. However, that would make things tedious, so I didn't do that.
- It seems like a huge coincidence that $X_4$ is odd.

Comment: I was writing a more detailed answer (and will continue), but that's how I usually answer, so thanks for your approach, I've voted up.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon take your time to write it up. If you have a different approach, I'd be interested in reading it. I find it easier to post a mostly complete answer, then take my time (like the past 40 mins) to refine the writeup / approach.

Comment: I really learnt a lot from this post! Thank you for spending so much time in writing!

Answer (score 2):

##### Finding the number of digits of $1024^k$

We can solve this question by noting a few basic things. (Note : This is designed to be a complete answer : another one provides the basic framework and leaves the author to fill in the details, and is also really nice).

The first, is that the powers of $1024$ have a very predictable number of digits , at least for small powers. To prove this, note that the number of digits of $1024^k$ is the unique $n$ such that $10^{n-1} < 1024^k < 10^{n}$. Taking logarithms to the base $10$ gives us the equivalent $n-1 < k \log_{10}{1024} < n$.

Note that $\log_{10}(1024) = \log_{10}(1000) + \log_{10}(1.024) = 3+\log_{10}(1.024)$, and one can check that $\log_{10}(1.024) = \frac{\ln(1.024)}{\ln(10)} \leq \frac{.024}{\ln(10)} \leq .024$ using the inequality $\ln(1+x) \leq x$.

In particular, we have $3 \leq \log_{10}(1024) \leq 3.024$, and therefore that $3k \leq k\log_{10}(1024) \leq 3k + 0.024k$.

It follows that for all $k < \frac 1{0.024} \approx 41.\overline{6}$ we have that $1024^k$ has $3k+1$ digits.

With this, we can hope to succeed if the solution is smaller than $41$.

---

##### A formula for $X_k$

There is a formula for $X_k$, at least up till $k = 41$. How do we find it? Well, we ask ourselves how we create it.

- At the end is $1024^k$. This takes up $3k+1$ digits.  So far, we have $1024^{k}$.
- Then we put $1024^{k-1}$ to the right of the earlier $3k+1$ digit number .So far we have $10^{3k+1} \times (1024^{k-1}) + 1024^{k}$.
- Then we put $1024^{k-2}$ to the right of this number, which has $3(k-1)+1 + 3k+1$ digits, so we have $10^{3k+1 + 3(k-1)+1} \times (1024^{k-2}) + 10^{3k+1} \times (1024^{k-1}) + 1024^k$.
- Going on till $1024$ is placed, we see the general formula which you can verify :
  $$
  X_k = \sum_{j=1}^k 10^{\left[\sum_{l=j+1}^{k}(3l+1)\right]}1024^j
  $$
  (where the summation in the exponent is empty for $j=k$).

---

##### A lemma for the number of times $2$ divides a sum of terms

At this point, it's worth asking how one can predict how many times $2$ divides a sum of terms. When we try it out with specific numbers, there seems to be no pattern, after all $31+1 = 32$ and on the LHS, both numbers are odd but on the RHS, $32$ has $2$ divide FIVE times into it!

However, there is a pattern, encapsulated by the following lemma :

> Let $\nu_2(k)$ denote the largest power of $2$ which divides $k$. Suppose that $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ are natural numbers. Let $I$ be the number of indices $i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $\nu_2(a_i) = \min\{\nu_2(a_1),...,\nu_2(a_n)\}$.
>
> - If $I$ is odd , then $$
>   \nu_2(a_1+...+a_n) =  \min\{\nu_2(a_1),...,\nu_2(a_n)\}
>   $$
> - If $I$ is even, then $$\nu_2(a_1+...a_n) > \min\{\nu_2(a_1),...,\nu_2(a_n)\}$$

In other words, if the smallest power of $2$ dividing any term in the sum is  also the smallest power of $2$ dividing an odd number of terms of the summation, then the smallest power of $2$ dividing the entire summation coincides with this minimum value. On the other hand, if the odd is replaced by even, we get a strict inequality.

This fact can be quite easily proven, I urge you to try to prove it.

---

##### Preparing to apply the lemma for $X_k$

For now, let's simplify the summation in the exponent for $X_k$ which is the sum of an arithmetic progression. You can find the formula easily, it is :
$$
X_k = \sum_{j=1}^k 10^{\frac{(k-j)(3j+3k+5)}{2}}1024^{j}
$$

We are naturally going to write $X_k = \sum_{j=1}^k A_{j,k}$, where $A_{j,k} = 10^{\frac{(k-j)(3j+3k+5)}{2}}1024^{j}$. So what is $\nu(A_{j,k})$ for a particular $j$ and $k$? That's right, once you split the two parts and find the $\nu_2$ of each part (note that $\nu_2(ab) = \nu_2(a)\nu_2(b)$ for all $a,b$), it is :
$$
\nu_2(A_{j,k}) = 10j + \frac{(k-j)(3j+3k+5)}{2}
$$

Recall that we are analysing the quotient of $X_k$ by $1024^k$ i.e. by $2^{10k}$. Given our lemma above, we should study the quantity $b_{j,k} = \nu_2(A_{j,k}) - 10k$ and find out when it equals zero (which is desirable), and when it's positive and negative.

Well, we have :
$$
b_{j,k} = 10j + \frac{(k-j)(3j+3k+5)}{2}-10k = \frac{3(k-j)(j+k-5)}{2} 
$$

We conclude that for a particular $j,k$, noting that $k-j$ is non-negative, the quantity $b_{j,k}$ above is :

- bigger than $0$ if and only if $k>j,j+k>5$.
- equal to $0$ if and only if $k=j$ OR $j+k=5$.
- smaller than $0$ if and only if $k>j,j+k<5$.

---

##### Answer and cases

###### Why $k=5$ is a suitable candidate

Fix a $k$. Recall from above that if $j=k$, then we know that $b_{j,k} = 0$. For every other $j<k$, if $j+k<5$ then $b_{j,k}<0$, and if $j+k>5$ then $b_{j,k} > 0$.

Using this, one sees that $b_{j,k} > 0$ for all $k \geq 5, 1 \leq j < k$, and $b_{k,k} = 0$. Therefore , $\nu_2(A_{j,k})>10k$  for all $k \geq 5, 1\leq j<k$ , and $\nu_2(A_{k,k})= 10k$. Thus, the minimum $\nu_2$ of $10k$ is attained by $1$ i.e. an odd number of indices in the summation for $X_k$. Using the lemma, we conclude that $\nu_2(X_k) = 10k$  for all $5 \leq k \leq 41$. Of course, the smallest of these is $5$.

We will now show that $k=2,3,4$ each don't work. The applications of the lemma below are analogous to how they were applied above (via the relation $b_{j,k}  = \nu_2(A_{j,k}) - 10k$).

###### Case $k=2$

For $k=2$, note that $b_{1,2}<0$ (as $1+2<5$) but $b_{2,2} = 0$, so applying the lemma we have $\nu_2(X_2) < 20$. (The minimum is attained at a unique index i.e. an odd number of indices).

###### Case $k=3$

For $k=3$, note that $b_{1,3}<0$ since $1+3<5$, while $b_{2,3} = b_{3,3} = 0$ (for the first, $2+3 = 5$ , and for the second $3=3$). Again, applying the lemma (again ,the minimum is attained at a unique index) we get $\nu_2(X_3) < 30$.

###### Case $k=4$

For $k=4$, note that $b_{1,4} = b_{4,4} = 0$ and $b_{2,4},b_{3,4} > 0$. However, when TWO(and hence an even number of) terms attain the same $\nu_2$, then the lemma's extension tells you that $\nu(X_4) > 40$.

The proof is complete $\blacksquare$.

---

##### Summary

- Finding the number of digits (the estimate can be used in other scenarios as well, and can be tightened considerably).
- Deducing a formula , using the above calculation, for concatenated numbers.
- Using a lemma that links $\nu_2(a_1+...+a_n)$ to $\min\{\nu_2(a_i)\}$, hence going from divisibility of the terms to divisibility of the sum by a power of $2$.

Comment: FWIW There are several parts where the exposition needs to be cleaned up. EG 1) When you say "So far we have $1024^{k-1}$, I think you mean $1024^k$?  2) It's not clear it the quote block is just the lemma, with the extension unstated.    $\quad$ For me, the biggest erroneous statement is saying "We would like it if ONE term had this quantity equal to 0, and for all other terms it was bigger than 0". Based on your lemma, it should be "A) Odd number of terms equal 0, rest > 0, or B) Even number of terms with the minimum index which is negative, and things work out".

Comment: @CalvinLin Having one $a_{j,k}$ as the minimal one is a sufficient condition, right? I mean , by "we would like it" I meant that this is a "sufficient" condition for $\nu_2(X_k) = 10k$, and it is. Yes, I agree a couple of $n$s and $k$s need to be fixed up, so I'll be doing this.

Comment: Yes, what you wrote is a sufficient condition. However, it is not necessary, which is where the exposition could be much clearer. EG Clarify that you're finding (a subset of) cases where the expression is odd, then dealing with the remainder cases separately.   $\quad$ Note: My solution doesn't only "provide hints". It's a complete solution where the reader needs to fill in the details.

Comment: @CalvinLin Sorry, I will make this correction in my answer. I did seek to be more detailed, so I'll make it clearer where I can.

Comment: @CalvinLin  I tidied it up a fair bit. Just let me know if anything is off. Thanks once again, and if you are not satisfied, then I will not bother you any more, I apologize for the mistakes in here.

Comment: This is much better. Adding titles to the sections definately helps. I have a personal preference for the summary/tldr to be at the top, as it gives a sense of where you're heading.  $\quad$  Note: Don't feel like you have to "satisfy me".

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks for the response! I'm sort of a "summary at the end" person : I haven't kept summaries at the top too often, and to be fair I haven't really thought about an explanation! Anyway, it's fun doing these contest problems!

Comment: Wow, it was too detailed( Like I asked for hints). But yes, I think it's really nicely written!

Comment: @SunainaPati It's my writing style, I will try to compromise on it next time!